# Here map import header issue in swift

Tags: swift, sqlite

I am implementing here map sdk in my project , but when I go for importing `#import <NMAKit/NMAKit.h>`
that time I got an error that is  Ambiguous use of 'count' in 
below line

```
        let fetchProfileQuery : String = "SELECT IFNULL(USER_NAME,''),IFNULL(EMAIL_ADD,''),IFNULL(ADDRESS,''),IFNULL(DOB,''),IFNULL(PHONE_NUMBER,'') FROM TBL_PROFILE"
    let fetchProfileLog = appDelegate.dbController.executeQuery(fetchProfileQuery).objectAtIndex(0)

    CommonClass_ViewController.writeInDebugFile("ViewController Name :- ProfileViewController , Method_Name : - fetchProfileData() , Query_Details : -  \(fetchProfileQuery) , \(fetchProfileLog.count)")
```

If I remove header file `#import <NMAKit/NMAKit.h>` then its working fine.